# block internet explorer from joomla site

Tags: joomla2.5

I have a Joomla site and I want to block Internet Explorers users visiting the site but showing them a custom page to upgrade to another browser.
thanx in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a bad idea and I hate IE. You have to keep in mind that there are many users that don't have the option to switch browsers - most users surfing from work are not allowed to install any software so you would be impacting your traffic pretty seriously.

Really, there is no valid reason not to support IE7/8 or newer. It's not hard to make sites work in IE if they are coded well. Stick to good practices and most issues are simply not an issue.

That said, if you REALLY want to do this, all you need is a simple bit of javascript that detects the browser's user agent then redirects as needed. There are hundreds of scripts for detecting user agents, just Google it.